# Retrieve the elevation from a point cloud with lastools?

Tags: point-cloud, lastools

I have a general question about how can I get the elevation (z) data from a pointcloud (las) along a trajectory. I have a shape file with x, y coordinates and I have the related .las files. And I am using lastools for the point cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say whether you have access to ArcMap or not and I am not familiar with lastools. IS this a tool kit in ArcMap? Anyway, I apologize in advance if the answer is not of any help. If you have access to ArcMap you can use this tool:
[image] and then use the raster calculator to extract the value that you need.

Comment: Thanks! I dind'nt know this tool in ArcMap, it can be very useful, but I have more than hundreds of files, so I need to automatize athe process. Lastools is a bunch of programs especially for processing lidar datas.

Comment: In that case you may want to create a single LAS aggregating them all together. Take a look at this  [link](http://http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/creating-a-las-dataset.htm) and then use the LAS Dataset to Raster tool to extract the z value for elevation.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please send the link agait...somehow it doesn't work...

Comment: I am sorry for the non functioning link: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/las-dataset/creating-a-las-dataset.htm